# IOS Anyway to have NSAttributedString throughout app. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, uifont

I have a font which is super skinny. In photoshop, I have added stroke to the font which makes it look more appealing. When transferring it to iOS I couldn't add a stroke unless I used NSAttributedString. By using the NSAttributedString I got one of my UILabels to look exactly how it looks in photoshop however the issue is that I will have hundreds of UILabels by the time my app is finished. Is there a way where I don't have to manually connect each UILabel to its respective controller and set its attributedText one by one. Any suggestions would help.

Comment: It sounds like you should subclass the label & set up the properties you want in an initializer.

Comment: any help on how I should do that? I am thinking creating a UILabel class and under initializer put in the attributes? I would connect the UILabel to the class, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @AdamPro13 suggestion, you could create a protocol extension for your `NSAttributedString`:

So, create `NSAttributedStringExtension.swift` with something like that:

```
protocol NSAttributedStringExtension {
    static func attributed(string:String, font:UIFont, color:UIColor) -> NSAttributedString
}

extension NSAttributedString : NSAttributedStringExtension {
    class func attributed(string:String, font:UIFont, color:UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {

        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color]
        return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attrs)
    }
}
```

And you could make several different functions for different label types.
Just apply then on your label (rough code):

```
let label:UILabel
let font:UIFont
let color:UIColor
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString.attributed("test", font: font, color: color)
```

Note: the font and colour you could setup in your protocol extension function

Comment: This answer is great. Between AdamPro13 and your answer I think I have come up with a solution. Create a class (BaseUILabel class) and assign all UILabels to that class. This saves me the hassle of connect each UILabel to a controller then calling .attributed function. For table-based labels, I can just call the extension. Thank you both very much for such an insightful solution!

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching and then I stumbled upon this question. I think you want a category for `UILabel`. I have one very helpful method from my old Cocoapod library called **GPKit** https://github.com/glennposadas/gpkit-ios that I made before. But this code below is updated and documented.

```
import UIKit

/// Category for UILabel helper functions
extension UILabel {
    /// A helper function for setting up the normal properties of the label.
    /// This means that the label has no special attributes.
    /// This uses the system font.
    func setup(_ text: String, fontSize: CGFloat, weight: UIFont.Weight = .regular, italic: Bool = false, textColor: UIColor = .lalaDarkGray, numberOfLines: Int = 1, textAlignment: NSTextAlignment = .natural) {
        self.font = italic ? UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: fontSize) : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: weight)
        self.text = text
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.numberOfLines = numberOfLines
        self.textAlignment = textAlignment
    }

    /**
     Sets up the label with two different kinds of attributes in its attributed text.

     - Author: Glenn

     - Important:
         - primaryString = "Total:"
         - secondaryString = "123"
         - This means that the function will concat the secondary string into the primary string and highlights the secondary string.
         - Using the highlightedText means the highlightedText itself is in the primaryString.

     - parameters:
        - primaryString: the normal attributed string.
        - secondaryString: the bold or highlighted string.
        - highlightedText: this one is like the secondary string, if this is provided, then the secondaryString is ignored. This is to be used if the highlighted text is not to be concatinated at the end of the primaryString
     */
    func setAttributedText(
        primaryString: String,
        textColor: UIColor,
        font: UIFont,
        secondaryString: String = "",
        secondaryTextColor: UIColor? = nil,
        secondaryFont: UIFont? = nil,
        highlightedText: String? = nil,
        textAlignment: NSTextAlignment = .center,
        numberOfLines: Int = 1,
        lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 1) {

        var textToBeHighlighted = ""
        var completeString: String!

        self.numberOfLines = numberOfLines

        if let highlightedText = highlightedText {
            textToBeHighlighted = highlightedText
            completeString = primaryString
        } else {
            if secondaryString.hasValidValue() {
                textToBeHighlighted = secondaryString
                completeString = "\(primaryString) \(secondaryString)"
            } else {
                completeString = primaryString
            }
        }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let completeAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: completeString, attributes: [
                .font: font,
                .foregroundColor: textColor,
                .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ]
        )

        let secondStringAttribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: secondaryFont ?? font,
            .foregroundColor: secondaryTextColor ?? textColor,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
        ]

        let range = (completeString as NSString).range(of: textToBeHighlighted)

        completeAttributedString.addAttributes(secondStringAttribute, range: range)

        self.attributedText = completeAttributedString
    }
}
```

You can use it in every label you have like so:

```
internal lazy var label_Total: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.setAttributedText(
        primaryString: "Total".localized(),
        textColor: .gray,
        font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0),
        secondaryString: "",
        secondaryTextColor: .blue,
        secondaryFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: customFontWeight)
    )
    return label
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard and want to use UILabels as normal, then you can try creating a UILabel subclass as shown below and using it in your storyboards as a custom class. This will effectively replace the text with the attributedText you want although you wont see it until runtime.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(19),
                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]
        attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text!, attributes: attrs)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JonLz for you reply. Your answer is similar to what AdamPro13 stated. At first I was confused as to what I should do but after carefully reading his suggestion I figured our that I should do it that that. Thank you!
Aleksey also helped by giving me a solution for all the labels that are not static - e.g. cells.textLabels